# Date - Data type mismatch in criteria expression in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which stores birthdate in the field `DateValueOf`. I am creating a query where user can input any date and the query will return customers which have birthday on that day.

For this, I am trying to convert all  the year in `DateValueOf` to current year.

```
eg > #13-10-1996# to #13-10-2016#
eg > #13-10-2001# to #13-10-2016#
```

So that I will then ask user to select date from date picker and run the below query.

```
SELECT CustomerID 
WHERE FormatDateTime(DateValue(DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month([DateValueOf]),Day([DateValueOf]))),2) >= #13-10-2016#
```

> But this SQL statement produces an error `data type mismatch in criteria expression`

Please highlight my mistake. Thanks in advance. I am also open to any other way to get who's birthday it is today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you receive the date from a date picker Control (call it: `myDatePicker`), today's date, returned by function `Date()` is not relevant.
And unless you want the age, `Year()` is not relevant either.

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM MyTableName
WHERE Month(myDatePicker) = Month([DateValueOf]) AND Day([DateValueOf]) = Day([myDatePicker])
```

If you want the customer's age at this birthday, you can add the calculation to the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Year(myDatePicker) - Year(DateValueOf) As CustomerAge 
FROM MyTableName
WHERE Month(myDatePicker) = Month([DateValueOf]) AND Day([DateValueOf]) Day([myDatePicker])
```

Comment: Nice Suggestion. I have implemented your solution in my project. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about formatting the date, just use a date comparison:

```
SELECT CustomerID 
WHERE DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month([DateValueOf]),Day([DateValueOf]))
   >= #13-10-2016#
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, But still getting error. After much research and trial and error, I came to know that I am getting `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` because `DateValueOf` field is empty in some instance. How do I manage this?